# if number is greater in textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement

I am new to this so please be patient, I am having a bit of trouble with if statement.

I want to print a message in textbox 1 if textbox 2 is over 0.5. Can anyone help please.

```
class Product
{
    public string collectmessage1()
    {
        return "Collect your product";
    }

    if (txtMoney.Text > 0.5)
    {
        Product cokecollect;
        cokecollect = new Product();

        txtProducts.Text = cokecollect.collectmessage1();
    }
```

Comment: People have given you answers below. You need to convert a string to a number type (double or decimal) before comparing or it won't work. But for future reference, please include what error message(s) you are getting in your question.

Comment: Just a note, unrelated to the question. Your code is not structured correctly. You need to stick that if() statement into a method of some sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TextBox.Text` property returns a `String` which cannot be compared to a `0.5`, a `double` object. Using your code will throw an error

> Error1 Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'double'

Parse the string returned by the text property of your textbox to double before comparing and you will get rid of this error. As Velous said, TryParse is a better choice in case of a format exception.

```
double no;
bool valid = double.TryParse(txtMoney.Text, out no);
if (valid && no > 0.5) {

       Product cokecollect;
       cokecollect = new Product();

      txtProducts.Text = cokecollect.collectmessage1();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `double.TryParse` to parse the `string` to a `double`

```
double result = 0.0;
if (double.TryParse(txtMoney.Text, out result) &&  result > 0.5)
{

   Product cokecollect;
   cokecollect = new Product();

   txtProducts.Text = cokecollect.collectmessage1();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (decimal.Parse(txtMoney.Text) > 0.5m)
{
     Product cokecollect;
     cokecollect = new Product();

     txtProducts.Text = cokecollect.collectmessage1();
}
```

To prevent exceptions when you money format is incorrect, you can use `decimal.TryParse` method instead:

```
decimal money = 0m;
decimal.TryParse(txtMoney.Text, out money);
if (money > 0.5m)
{
         Product cokecollect;
         cokecollect = new Product();

         txtProducts.Text = cokecollect.collectmessage1();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a `TextBox` and you are allowing input from the users, I would personally use `double.TryParse` instead of `double.parse`

```
double myNumber;

bool isValid = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out myNumber);

if (isValid)
{
    if (myNumber > 0.5)
    { 
        ...
    }
}
```

This way if the user inputs something bad (letters for instance) you do not get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement must be inside a function or the code won't compile.